# How to configure pytest in FastAPI?

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I'm trying to write some tests for my FastAPI -application. I have defined `app` in `main.py` like this: `app = FastAPI()`. I try to import this in my test `test_api.py`:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_main():
  # test code
```

When I run the tests I get these errors:

```
E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for Settings
E   SERVER_NAME
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)
E   SERVER_HOST
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)
E   PROJECT_NAME
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)
E   DATABASE_URL
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

How should I configure the tests so I could run them successfully?

Edit. This is the structure of the app.

```
project
│   .env
│  
│
└───app
    │  
    │ 
    |───app
    |   │ main.py
    |   │
    |   |___config
    |           config.py
    | 
    |
    |───tests
         test_file01.py
```

Comment: How are you creating your Settings object? Seems like you don't have the `.env` file loaded that you expect to have loaded - are you running your tests from the directory with the `.env` file?

Comment: @MatsLindh I edited the basic structure of my app to the question. The Settings object is created inside the `config.py` like this: `settings = Settings()`.

Comment: Yes, but the location of _where you're running the tests from_ is important for whether it picks up the `.env` file or not. If you're running them from inside your `app/tests` directory, the `.env` file won't get loaded. The same will be an issue if you're running them in your IDE. You'll need to set the correct working directory in that case.

Comment: @MatsLindh I've tried running the tests from all different locations and the error remains the same.

Comment: Add enough information to reproduce the error in that case (i.e. add the settings file, a small script that creates the app and an example .env file that shows the issue), but usually this is caused by the CWD being in a different location than where the `.env` file is.

Comment: i try with app.app.main , but since theres some route in my app.main, it casue another problem , do the author @Ir_optim solve the problem yet ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the environment vars in test,

```
import os
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = 'server_name'
os.environ['SERVER_HOST'] = 'server_host'
os.environ['PROJECT_NAME'] = 'project_name'
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'DATABASE_URL'

from main import app
client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_main():
  # test code
```

The app import needs to be after the env var definition, it's better to set your application as fixture.